# Sending messages with whastapp business cloud api

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

When I send a message

```
curl -X  POST \
'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "16315555555","text": {"body" : "hello world!"}}'
```

I receive the following error:

```
 invalid request #12 singular published story api is deprecated for version v2.4 and higher
```

what does it mean????

I am expecting to send the message